# Why I'm unable to fill the input fields using react use State hook?

Tags: reactjs, web, react-hooks, mern, react-fullstack

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form"; 
import classNames from "classnames";
import { useState } from "react";


function App() {
      const { register, handleSubmit,formState: { errors } } = useForm();
      console.log(errors);
      const onSubmit = data => console.log(data);
```

**Here i use useState hook**
First I use only one state for all fields

```
  const [userData,setUserData] = useState({
    userName:"",
    CNIC:"",
    number:"",
    email:"",
    Car_Name:"",
    Car_Model:"",
    Car_Color:"",
    Brand_Name:"",
    Address:"",

  });
```

Then store it Dynamically for every field

```
  let name,value;

  const postUserData = (event) => {
    name = event.traget.name;
    value = event.traget.value;
```

**Even I update it through setUserData.But still it not working**
And here I Update it for every field dynamically.But not updating??

```
     setUserData({...userData,[name]:value});

  };
  
  return (
<div>
```

**There are the some fields**

```
<div className="container">
      <br />
      <h1 className="text-center text-success">Form validation in React</h1>
      <br />
      <div className="form-group my-3 ">
        <form name="Registration_form" id="Form" action="" onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
          
          <div className="form-group my-3">
            <label htmlFor="name">Name:<span style={{fontWeight:"bold",color:"red"}}>*</span></label>
           
            <input 
              type="text" 
              name="userName" 
              id="Name" 
              value={userData.userName}
              onChange={postUserData}
              className={classNames("form-control",{"is-invalid":errors.Name,})}  
              autoComplete="off" 
              {...register('Name', 
              { required: true,
                maxLength: 15,
                pattern: /^[A-Za-z]+$/
              
              })
              }

              
              />

            <span id="name" className="text-danger fw-bold">{errors.Name?.type === "required"  && "This field is required"}</span>

            <span id="name" className="text-danger fw-bold">{errors.Name?.type ==="maxLength" && "Length Should be less then 15"}</span>

            <span id="name" className="text-danger fw-bold">{errors.Name?.type === "pattern"  && "Digits are not allow"}</span>

          </div>
          <div className="form-group my-3">
            <label htmlFor="CNIC">CNIC:<span style={{fontWeight:"bold",color:"red"}}>*</span></label>
            
            <input 
              type="text" 
              name="CNIC" 
              id="CNIC"
              value={userData.CNIC}
              onChange={postUserData} 
              className={classNames("form-control",{"is-invalid":errors.CNIC,})}  
              placeholder="XXXXX-XXXXXXX-X" 
              autoComplete="off"
              {...register('CNIC', 
              { 
                required: true,
                minLength:15,
                maxLength:15,
                pattern:/[0-9]/g,
                validate: {
                  format: (value) => /^[0-9]{5}[-]{1}[0-9]{7}[-]{1}[0-9]{1}$/.test(value)
                }
              })
              } 
            
              />

            <span id="cnic" className="text-danger fw-bold">{errors.CNIC?.type === "required"  && "CNIC is required"}</span>

            <span id="cnic" className="text-danger fw-bold">{errors.CNIC?.type ==="minLength" && "Length must be equal to 15"}</span>

            <span id="cnic" className="text-danger fw-bold">{errors.CNIC?.type ==="maxLength" && "Length must be equal to 15"}</span>

            <span id="cnic" className="text-danger fw-bold">{errors.CNIC?.type === "pattern"  && "Charaters are not allow"}</span>

            <span id="cnic" className="text-danger fw-bold">{errors.CNIC?.type === "format"  && "Invalid format"}</span>

            
          </div>
          <div className="form-group my-3">
            <label htmlFor="number">Mobile Number:<span style={{fontWeight:"bold",color:"red"}}>*</span> </label>
            
            <input 
             type="text" 
             name="number" 
             id="number" 
             value={userData.number}
              onChange={postUserData} 
             className={classNames("form-control",{"is-invalid":errors.number,})}  
             placeholder="XXXX-XXXXXXX" 
             autoComplete="off" 
             {...register('number', 
              { 
                required: true,
                pattern:/[0-9]/g,
                validate: {
                  format: (value) => /^((\+92)?(0092)?(92)?(0)?)(3)([0-9]{2})((-?)|( ?))([0-9]{7})$/gm.test(value)
                }
                // /^((\+92)?(0092)?(92)?(0)?)(3)([0-9]{2})((-?)|( ?))([0-9]{7})$/gm

              
              })
              }
            
             />

              <span id="number" className="text-danger fw-bold">{errors.number?.type === "required"  && "Number is required"}</span>

              <span id="number" className="text-danger fw-bold">{errors.number?.type === "pattern"  &&"Charaters are not allow"}</span>

              <span id="number" className="text-danger fw-bold">{errors.number?.type === "format"  && "Invalid format"}</span>

          </div>
```

**This is some fields can anyone check the mistake why i am unable to fill the fields??**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you are using state together with react-hook-form?

The whole purpose of this library is to use uncontrolled inputs.

Did you check what exacly `register(...)` gives you? There is **onChange** that overrides your **onChange**.

**No need to use state** when you are using react-hook-form

Comment: react-hook-form use for validation and userState use for storing data 
And then send it to database

Comment: if not use, together useState with react-hook-form then how can validate and store data and then send to fire base data base??

Comment: useForm gives you 'handleSubmit'. Use it like this: handleSubmit((values) => ... use values here). And pass it to form onSubmit. Values are already stored in useForm. Check this: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-handlesubmit-v7-uqmiy

Comment: then how to pass it to firebase data base

Comment: You have the values onSubmit, do whatever you want with them. useForm also gives you 'getValues' and 'watch', that you can see the current values outside of submit handler. Check this: https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/watch

Comment: `function App() {
  const { register, handleSubmit,formState: { errors } } = useForm();
  // console.log(errors);
  const onSubmit = data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data));

const postData = async (e)=>{
    e.preventDefault();
    const res = await fetch("https://test1-5022f-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/reactformData.json",
    {
      method:"POST",
      header:{
        "content-type":"application/json",

      },
      body:JSON.stringify(data)
    }
    
    )
  };

<form name="Registration_form" id="Form" action="" method="POST" onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>`

Comment: its not working what's i pass in body data or what??
` body:JSON.stringify(data)     }          ) `

Comment: Your question was about inputs and form. I told you what was your problem with useForm and state. Now you are asking about firebase? If your form works, mark this question as solved and ask another question about firebase. Someone may answer you. Check console.log(data) after submit, if you get all the values, that means your form works and your question is solved. Firebase is for another question